# What are some smooth ways to slide(drag) not swipe but slide(drag) from one view controller to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, drag

I posted a question earlier wanting to know how Snapchat achieved their navigation system. It's very smooth how you can drag one viewController to another. I'm posting this question to see if anybody has any direction on how I can drag one view controller to another horizontally?

Can you use a pan gesture recognizer to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know Snapchat, but I think what you are after may be a UIPageViewController. See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)  If you configure its delegate appropriately, it will do the gesture recognition for you.

Comment: Depends what look you want. If you want it to scroll over as you drag, you can use a page view controller as pbasdf said. If you want  the incoming view do drag over and cover up the old view (which stays in place) then you need to make your own animation. It can be controlled with a pan gesture recognizer.

Comment: Okay cool cool. What about adding a container viewController and adding like three child view controllers putting all three in a scrollView with paging enabled? My biggest concern with that is the memory since with that option it seems everything would be on the container.. @rdelmar

Comment: That's the same thing that you would get by using a page view controller set to UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll.

Comment: Okay gotcha thanks a lot! I think thats a good starting point!